# How to deal with 256 bit numbers in javascript and perfom bitwise operations on them?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How to deal with 256 bit numbers in javascript and perfom biwise operations on them?

From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp) I have read that

> JavaScript stores numbers as 64 bits floating point numbers, but all
> bitwise operations are performed on 32 bits binary numbers.
>
> Before a bitwise operation is performed, JavaScript converts numbers
> to 32 bits signed integers.
>
> After the bitwise operation is performed, the result is converted back
> to 64 bits JavaScript numbers.

I am working with solidity and so it would be great if I could manipulate 256 bit numbers in javascript. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use bigints - bitwise operators work on them too.

Comment: Are biginits 256bits?

Comment: Bigints are arbitrary-bitsized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for this problem will to use BigInts, which are arbitrarily large integers. You can do bitwise operations, but both operands must be BigInts, as an example:

```js
const x = (12n ** 122n) & (13n ** 133n);

x; // 456858437811811283460933542382254067662103063706637216731032202770157889962434550961221416858884249781343525362849766767350670950400n
```

Another way would be to use the bytes of the number directly and apply the bitwise operations independently on each byte, but this way is more complex and you cannot represent these numbers with the simple number primitive. But if the platform you are running the code do not support `BigInt` primitive this is the only way.

Comment: I am using angular, or what do you mean by platfrom? What is meant by `arbitrarily large integers`? I google the meaning of `arbitrary` and I see it is a synonym for random.

Comment: @YulePale arbitrarily large: as large as necessary, no number is too large.
platform: BigInts are a relatively new feature of JS, not supported on every platform: https://caniuse.com/bigint

Comment: Does the platfrom restrictions apply when dealing with frameworks like angular and libraries like react?

Comment: By platform I meant browser (old browsers do not support BigInts), node or other environments that run javascript.